# modern exposition of exact ground state of classical XY model or Ising model

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, nonlinear-optimization

What is the state of art technique in solving exact ground state of Heisenberg model, meaning minimization of the H terms (hamiltonian) provided infinite spin space?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Heisenberg_model

I read that there is a method called Bethe Ansatz. But as Ansatz suggests, is it a mathematical method or just some heuristics? Thank you. Are there some modern exposition of Bethe Ansatz or other methods to solve the exact ground state problem? Thank you.

Comment: The method called "Bethe Ansatz" applies to quantum models, not to classical spin models. The classical Heisenberg model in two or more dimensions, in a nonzero magnetic field, has no exact solution, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.... actually, rather than finding the exact partition function. What we want is the ground state configurations of spins....

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163658/24498.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.